# dropbox api Oauth response "No scope requested can be granted for this app"

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am building an application that would need access to dropbox files which used Oauth 2.0 to authenticate, I have been following the tutorial step by step below, using POSTMAN to get access token by authorization code. But I couldn't get the same result as the tutorial video (16:39) on my request. Here is my response:

"Error (400)
It seems the app you were using submitted a bad request. If you would like to report this error to the app's developer, include the information below.

More details for developers:
No scope requested can be granted for this app."

I also noticed there's an update on dropbox API when I created my app in dropbox app console, there's an option called "scoped access" instead of the two options (dropbox API or dropbox business API) shown in the video. do anyone knows how to fix the problem? thank you

Tutorial link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpmEkNJubHA&t=921s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that none of the "scopes" being requested during the authorization flow are registered for the app. When using a scoped app, you need to enable all of the scopes that your app will need before initiating the authorization flow with those scopes.

You can enable whatever scopes you need from the "Permissions" tab on the app's page on [the App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps).

You can find more information on how the OAuth flow and scopes work in [the OAuth Guide](https://www.dropbox.com/lp/developers/reference/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization).